# [SQL]How to fill an object which has a list from another table in one SELECT?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mybatis

I wonder if it is possible with the sql annotation in mybatis to have this:

This is my java object:

```
Group
---------------
String name 
String description 
String coordinator
List<String> groupRoles;
```

I would like to have a query which get the group data from the GROUPS table and also the roles of the group which are in the GROUP_ROLES table.

```
GROUPS_ROLES
GROUPNAME ROLENAME

GROUPS
GROUPNAME DESCRIPTION COORDINATOR
```

Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want SQL query means this will help you.

```
SELECT * 
FROM group g INNER JOIN group_roles r 
ON g.name = r.group_name
```